# Bid and asks above last closing price on a weekend?

Tags: trading, after-hours-trading

I am a bit confused about the situation.

What I understand is that the last trade, on friday, was at 74.212. However, once the market reopens on monday, the initial bid and asks will be those in the image. Is that correct?

[image: Situation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bid is the highest price that someone is willing to pay for a purchase and the ask is the lowest price that someone is willing to sell at, at any given moment in time.  They have nothing to do with what price the security last traded at.  What the bid and the ask are when the market opens Monday morning will reflect current orders on the book at that time.